# angularjs watch service variable changes in controller and directive

Tags: angularjs

I have been struggling with $watch for long time. I want to have $watch to be triggered from controller and directive, when the shared variable in service is changed. But for some reason, they are not get triggered. I am a newbie for Angularjs and probably have wrong understanding with how $watch works. Here is my experimental code. http://jsfiddle.net/b3A8B/84/

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', ['myService', function(myService) {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, myService) {       
        },
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope) {
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return myService.tag;
            }, 

            function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log("Inside directive watch");
                console.log(newVal);
                console.log(oldVal);
            }, true);

        }
    }}]);

myApp.service('myService', function() {
    var tags = {
        a: true,
        b: true
    };

    var setFalseTag = function() {
        console.log("Within myService->setFalseTag");
        tags.a = false;
        tags.b = false;
    };

    return {
            tag: tags,
            setFalseTagA: setFalseTag
    };
});


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.setFTag = function() {
        console.log("Within MyCtrl->setFTag");
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("delay");myService.setFalseTagA();}, 2000)
    };        

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return myService.tag;
    }, 

    function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log("Inside controller watch");
        console.log(newVal);
        console.log(oldVal);
    }, true);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the setTimeout() for?
This browser's native function will not lead to dirty checking and so ng will not notice the change (until the next dirty-checking is triggered from somewhere else).

If you remove it, or replace it by $timeout (after injecting that, of course), the watch is triggered.

Comment: Yes, using $timeout can trigger the watch in controller, but cannot trigger it in directive. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks stephen for the quick reply. I move $timeout into service, then the watch in controller is triggered but directive is still not triggered. Here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/b3A8B/96/. Basically what i want is to see controller and directive are both able to detect the changes and react whenever the service variable changes.

Comment: 1) You directive is not used at all in the fiddle - I added a <div my-directive></div> to the HTML.
2) There's a typo in your code: $scope.$watch() inside the directive should be scope.$watch (without the leading $)